# Ubunu 20.04 how do i install my Canon 2540S using Cups

Tags: networking, printing

I am a novice with Linux and just taken the plunge to switch from Windows. I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and was very happy to set up file sharing using Samba and my Canon 2540s as a shared printer - then I recieved a warning!

Printer driver support is deprecated and on next update my printer will no longer work - because printer drivers will not work on later CUPS versions. - the new implementation is using CUPS.

I have Googled extensively and tried *so many* methods whilst still struggling to understand CUPS, but finally managed to get a CUPS-BRF-PRINER installed - but it will not print to my printer. So my current status is -

- A shared printer installed using drivers that works
- A CUPS print server that will not print to my printer
- On next update my working printer installation will stop working and I will be left with CUPS that doesn't print to my printer

---

I finally found I could install a "cups client driver" for the Canon Pixma MG 2540S by first installing the foomatic database like so:

```
sudo apt-get install cups cups-client "foomatic-db"

sudo apt-get install -y foomatic-db
```

Then when I open http://localhost:631/admin and add printer I get many more printers to choose from in the dropdown, including Canon Pixma 2540S.

But I still got the message that printer drivers will not work on later CUPS versions. I am not sure if this is a standard message and I am now OK or not. I suspect I will still need a PPD.

So I will post new question as new topic.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found I could install a "cups client driver" for the Canon Pixma MG 2540S by first installing the foomatic database like so (use only one or the other, they apparently do the same thing):

```
sudo apt-get install cups cups-client "foomatic-db"

or

sudo apt-get install -y foomatic-db
```

Then when I open http://localhost:631/admin and add printer I get many more printers to choose from in the dropdown, including Canon Pixma 2540S.

But I still got the message that printer drivers will not work on later CUPS versions. I am not sure if this is a standard message and I am now OK or not. I suspect I will still need a PPD at some point.

So I will post new question as new topic.